# What does the JB instruction mean in assembly

Tags: lcd, programming, assembly

I am looking at an ST7066U controller for a 2x16 LCD. The datasheet has these assembly instructions that I would like to change to C code.

```
CHK_BUSY: ;Check Busy Flag
CLR RS
SETB RW
SETB E
JB P1.7,$
CLR E
RET
```

What does `JB P1.7, $` mean?

Comment: This type of question is usually answered directly by just looking at the datasheet or assembly language reference for your particular processor.

Comment: High-time you start to learn how to read datasheets.

Answer (score 5):

The JB instruction branches to the address specified in the second operand if the value of the bit specified in the first operand is 1. The bit that is tested is not modified. No flags are affected by this instruction.

Source: https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_jb.htm

Comment: I read that in the datasheet, I understood that part, if the first operand `P1.7` is HIGH, then it shall go to the address in the second operand `$`, however I didn't understand it in this context, which address does `$` points to?

Comment: The $ refers to the address of the instruction itself, so the instruction is executed over and over again, until the device is no longer busy.

Answer (score 4):

The ST7066U's datasheet has some example code for the 8051 MPU.

From the [8051's instruction set](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/comp/8051/set8051.html#51jb):

```
Operation:   JB
Function:    Jump if Bit Set
Syntax:      JB bit addr, reladdr

Instructions         OpCode  Bytes  Flags
JB bit addr,reladdr  0x20    3      None

Description: JB branches to the 
address indicated by reladdr if 
the bit indicated by bit addr 
is set. 
If the bit is not set program 
execution continues with the 
instruction following the JB 
instruction.
```